# how to delete multiple row of table which generated through listview by using checkbox

Tags: hibernate, wicket

I am working on wicket. I used a checkbox for every row in a table which is generated through Listview. I want to delete a particular row by using checkbox selection.

This table can be generated by using Listview which shows table data. Please tell me at least how I would get the row id by selection of multiple checkboxes. Please tell me how could I do this?

```
package com.cerebrum.pages;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxRequestTarget;
import org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.form.AjaxButton;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.CheckBox;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.CheckGroup;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.CheckGroupSelector;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.TextField;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.list.ListItem;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.list.ListView;
import org.apache.wicket.model.CompoundPropertyModel;
import org.apache.wicket.model.PropertyModel;

import com.cerebrum.common.Home;
import com.cerebrum.hibernate.Users;
import com.cerebrum.hibernate.UsersHome;
import com.cerebrum.pojo.AdminViewUserModel;

public class AdminViewUser extends Home
{
    UsersHome usersHome=new UsersHome();
    List<AdminViewUserModel> listCal = new ArrayList<AdminViewUserModel>();
    AdminViewUserModel adminViewUserModel=new AdminViewUserModel(); 

    public AdminViewUser()
    {
        super();
        add(new AdminViewUserForm());
    }

    public class AdminViewUserForm extends Form
    {
        public AdminViewUserForm()
        {
            super("AdminViewUserForm");
            setModel(new CompoundPropertyModel(adminViewUserModel));

            List<Users> lstUsers=usersHome.getUserInfo();
            for(Users users:lstUsers)
            {
                listCal.add(new AdminViewUserModel(users.getFirstName(),
                    users.getMiddleName(),users.getLastName(),users.getDateOfBirth(),
                    users.getEmailId(),users.getMobileNo(),users.getUserName(),
                    users.getPassword()));
            }

            ListView listViewCal = new ListView("listViewCal", listCal) 
            {
                protected void populateItem(ListItem item) 
                {
                    AdminViewUserModel model=(AdminViewUserModel)item.getDefaultModelObject();
                    CheckBox chkBoxSelect=new CheckBox("chkBoxSelect",new PropertyModel(model, "chkBoxSelect"));
                    item.add(chkBoxSelect);

                    TextField txtFname=new TextField("txtFname",new PropertyModel(model, "txtFname"));
                    item.add(txtFname);

                    TextField txtMname=new TextField("txtMname",new PropertyModel(model, "txtMname"));
                    item.add(txtMname);
                    TextField txtLname=new TextField("txtLname",new PropertyModel(model, "txtLname"));
                    item.add(txtLname);
                    TextField txtDOB=new TextField("txtDOB",new PropertyModel(model, "txtDOB"));
                    item.add(txtDOB);
                    TextField txtEmail=new TextField("txtEmail",new PropertyModel(model, "txtEmail"));
                    item.add(txtEmail);
                    TextField txtMobileNo=new TextField("txtMobileNo",new PropertyModel(model, "txtMobileNo"));
                    item.add(txtMobileNo);

                    TextField txtUserName=new TextField("txtUserName",new PropertyModel(model, "txtUserName"));
                    item.add(txtUserName);
                    TextField txtPassword=new TextField("txtPassword",new PropertyModel(model, "txtPassword"));
                    item.add(txtPassword);
                }
            };
            listViewCal.setOutputMarkupId(true);
            add(listViewCal);

            AjaxButton btnUpdate=new AjaxButton("btnUpdate")
            {
                @Override
                protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> arg1)
                {
                }
            };
            btnUpdate.setOutputMarkupId(true);
            add(btnUpdate);

            AjaxButton btnDelete=new AjaxButton("btnDelete")
            {
                @Override
                protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> arg1) 
                {
                }
            };
            add(btnDelete);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try to fix http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850232/data-comes-from-list-but-does-not-seen-onto-the-page first. don 't ask a lot of related questions. also, I recomend you do some reading regarding Wicket models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this: https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/listview-with-checkboxes.html

Comment: Thats the way I would do it to. Strange that wicket does not appear to have something for this common requieremend..

Comment: It's simple to implement though. For a framework designer, it's hard to choose which requirement is "common" and the main goal should be not to clutter up your framework with too many special functionality. Luckily Wicket is highly (and easily) customable.

Comment: Well, `CheckGroup` was created to cater for this common requirement.